# Reinstall Ubuntu with encrypted home directory?

Tags: system-installation, 10.04, encryption, format

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed with encrypted home directory. `/home` is on a a separate partition. Can I just boot from a 10.10 CD, reformat `/` and install as usual? Should it work if I use the same password? Is there anything else to keep in mind?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have previously done this on Ubuntu and Mandriva.

This will work and you will be able to mount your existing /home partition even if it is encrypted as long as you know the passphrase.

Thing to keep in mind is to set up the mount points correctly and don't accidentally format your /home partition.

Comment: Will the installer ask for the passphrase or will it be asked on first login? Or do ineed to enter it manually somewhere?

Comment: Actually you don't need to know the passphrase, just the password that will be asked when you first login after the installation.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a note of your mount passphrase. This is covered on the page

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory - "Recovering Your Mount Passphrase"

Answer (score 2):

It will work as long as you use the same username and password.

Actually you won't need the passphrase, just the password that will be asked when you first login after the installation.