# Cannot login in account with encrypted home after update from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: installation, upgrade, encryption, home-directory

After upgrading from ubuntu 11.04 to 10.10 I cannot access my encrypted home partition anymore. I can login, however all data stays encrypted.

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

gives:

```
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**Update**

I have several kernels installed (after the upgrade my menu.lst looks like this: http://paste.org/pastebin/view/35591) the problem is the same for all kernels. Booting from 2.6.32-27-generic and

```
adduser --encrypt-home tes
```

gives:

```
Adding user `tes' ...
Adding new group `tes' (1008) ...
Adding new user `tes' (1007) with group `tes' ...
Creating home directory `/home/tes' ...
Setting up encryption ...

************************************************************************
YOU SHOULD RECORD YOUR MOUNT PASSPHRASE AND STORE IT IN A SAFE LOCATION.
  ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
THIS WILL BE REQUIRED IF YOU NEED TO RECOVER YOUR DATA AT A LATER TIME.
************************************************************************

Error: Your kernel does not support filename encryption
ERROR:  Could not add passphrase to the current keyring
adduser: `/usr/bin/ecryptfs-setup-private -b -u tes' returned error code 1. Exiting.
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13177/how-do-i-recover-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory

Comment: Thanks, however the script doesn't find my home partition

Comment: If I give the home folder as argument after typing the MOUNT passphrase it says: `Error: Your kernel does not support filename encryption`

Comment: Is there any reason why you're booting the old 2.6.32 kernel?  That would be a remnant from Lucid (10.04), and have compatibility issues with the newer user space tools (e.g. here it is telling you that the old kernel's driver doesn't support file name encryption).

Comment: @'James Henstridge': I have the same problem with kernel 3.0.2. In the meantime I restored my old menu.lst but it does not change anything.

Comment: Solved: by upgrading some packages, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/802197

Answer (score 1):

Version 11.10 is still in alpha stage - this means development is early and things can be broken.

Encrypted folders and drives is one of these areas - see this ubuntuforums [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1790478).

**Rolling Back your System**

My advice is to rollback your system back to 11.04 until - at a minimum - the first or second beta of 11.10.

This assumes of course that you took an image backup of your system before the alpha upgrade.

If you didnt, you may have to just reinstall 11.04 from scratch - this could lose all your data on your hard-disk.

**Recoverying your Data**

If you have a separate /home partition - follow the advice in this [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012/reinstall-ubuntu-with-encrypted-home-directory).

Perhaps a better way is to backup all of your encrypted data using this [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13177/how-do-i-recover-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory).  Then do a fresh 11.04 install before copying back the data you have backed up.

Comment: If I install from scratch, will it recognize the encrypted home automatically?