# How to use encypted home directory after reinstallation

Tags: re-installation, ecryptfs

I reinstalled Ubuntu on a machine with encrypted home directories. After that installation I have edited the fstab to boot the old home partition in /home. After doing so I can not login anymore with LDM. If I type my password, witch is the same as before, after a short moment of activity I am referred back to login page.
I think this is due to the fact, that my home directory is not decrypted correctly. But I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012/reinstall-ubuntu-with-encrypted-home-directory) that this should work. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: You have to install first the package »ecryptfs-utils«. If you can't login to X, you can do this still by entering a console by typing Crt+Alt+F2, login there, and typ:

```
   sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

After that you can perform the following command:

```
   sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

This tool will ask you whether or not you remember your password, if this be the case you can type it in and after that your home directory should work again.

Comment: This provides read only access to home but does not enable logging in.